# Unable to install juggernaut using npm on mac Os X - version 10.7.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm, juggernaut

I followed the link below to install npm

http://shapeshed.com/setting-up-nodejs-and-npm-on-mac-osx/

Node -v 0.8.2 was installed properly.

Then I used the following command to install npm

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

but I got an error saying -

```
Failed to get tarball url for npm/1.1
```

I also cloned npm from github and then did make install but it stopped at the third line shown below.

```
npm http GET https://github.com/isaacs/ronnjs/tarball/master
npm http 200 https://github.com/isaacs/ronnjs/tarball/master
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/opts
```

After trying for sometime I then downloaded the install.sh file and then changed 
https://registry.npmjs.org/ to http://registry.npmjs.org/ at all places.

Then as a root user I ran the following command

```
bash path_to_install.sh
```

and npm -v = 1.1.42 was installed

But when I tried to install juggernaut with the following command

```
npm install -g juggernaut
```

It gets stuck at the following line and nothing happens.

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/juggernaut
```

I guess the problem is with the https url or the way I installed npm.

How can I fix this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I replaced https://registry.npmjs.org to http://registry.npmjs.org inside npm.